# jQuery ui autocomplete: Does not register IME events?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, ime

I'm trying to get [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) to work with English letters and Hebrew letters (utf-8).

**The widget itself works correctly when I type in english**, autocomplete pops up with results. However, to write Hebrew I use the virtual [google keyboard](https://developers.google.com/virtual-keyboard/v1/getting_started#hiworld) IME. When I actually type using the virtual keyboard **nothing pops up**. However, when I press the left or right **arrow keys**, the autocomplete pops up with Hebrew words.

Is there a way to get around this? So that the IME (google keyboard) key presses are registered as if I was using my keyboard for the jQuery autocomplete?

This is the script I have in my html if needed (for the virtual keyboard):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("elements", "1", {packages: "keyboard"});

var kbd;

function onLoad() {
  kbd = new google.elements.keyboard.Keyboard(
      [google.elements.keyboard.LayoutCode.HEBREW],
      ['project']); // 'project' is the input box
}

// If the keyboard is visible, hide it.
// If the keyboard is invisible, show it.
function toggleVisible() {
  var button = document.getElementById('btVisible');
  if (kbd.isVisible()) {
    kbd.setVisible(false);
    document.getElementById('btVisible').value = 'Show';
  } else {
    kbd.setVisible(true);
    document.getElementById('btVisible').value = 'Hide';
  }
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

(I know I'm answering an old post.)

I have no knowledge about Hebrew, but I had an issue with jQuery UI Autocomplete and Japanese IME. Maybe the following ticket might help?
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5933

Here's my workaround for the issue:
https://gist.github.com/k4200/1192189

HTH